# ClickOnce manifest error "The method you call cannot work on installed applications"

Tags: vsto, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce VSTO manifest I generate for an Office plugin.  When I try to install it, it grinds away for a while, and then gives the following error:

"The method you call cannot work on installed applications."

Googling for that error message doesn't give anything useful.  What can cause this error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be other causes, but in my case, it's marking it for "install" under the <deployment> tag:

```
<deployment install="true">
```

should be:

```
<deployment install="false">
```

The plugin VSTO should not be installed as a standalone application, it's depending on the target Office application to handle it as a plugin.

It looks like install="true" should be used in cases where you're installing from a .application, not a .vsto file.